# Spring Integration communication between contexts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I would like to fix the following scenario:

1:N Spring Contexts (Parent/children)

- The parent context contains a JMS inputChannel that will receive an
  String message.
- Each child context contain a TCP adapter (sender and receiver)
  connected to a different IP:PORT

My question is how to connect a `@Gateway` defined in the parent context with the correspondent child. I could use a `@Router` by payload even a `@Filter` with headers but my problem is about the `@Component` visibility between different contexts. How Can I configure this scenario?

At this moment, I have:

```
Gateway (parent) -> Transformer (parent) -> TCP sender (Child)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it is working, including a `@Transformer` where input/output channels are from both contexts. In my example:

```
@Transformer(inputChannel="inputChannel", outputChannel="toTcpChannel")

@Transformer(inputChannel="fromTcpChannel", outputChannel="outputChannel")
```

- `toTcpChannel` and `fromTcpChannel` from the child context
- `inputChannel` and `outputChannel` from the parent context